# jQuery AJAX call preventing events

Tags: jquery, events

I have a page that has three items in close proximity (a textbox, a drop down list, and a hyperlink.) Each item has a JavaScript event that ultimately calls the same function that updates the page content. The problem occurs when a user changes the content of the textbox and then clicks the hyperlink without leaving the textbox. The textbox’s change event fires and its code works fine, but the button’s click event never fires (a console.log line at the top of the event confirms that it is never called). No error is thrown and the events that do fire appear to be working perfectly. The button’s event will fire if the button is clicked at other times. For example, if the user changes the textbox and tabs away and then clicks the hyperlink, both events end up firing. Likewise, if the user changes the content of the textbox and then clicks somewhere else on the page and then on the button, both events end up firing.

The change event makes an AJAX call. If this AJAX call is removed, both events fire (the problem goes away). I changed the AJAX call to a different AJAX call (a simpler one), and it also prevented the second event from firing.

I created a separate application with the same JavaScript library versions and attempted to re-create the problem in a more controlled and simpler environment. I was not able to re-create the problem at all - everything I tried worked - both events fired.

Obviously, this is quite frustrating. Does anyone have any idea what about the AJAX call might be causing the second event to never execute?

I'm working with an ASP.Net MVC 3 application, jQuery 1.7.1.1, jQuery.UI 1.8.17 and autoNumeric 1.7.4.

This code is my test code that works, but it basically reveals the structure of the code that is failing to work. Hopefully it helps clarify what's happening.

```
// This function exists like this because the existing code I'm trying to fix
// works like this -- these events are configured inside a function that
// is called from within some of the event handlers. There is good reason for 
// this, but outside the scope of this problem (I think).
InitializeFunction = function () {
    $("#txtAdjustment").on('change', function () {
        console.log('Textbox Changed');
        TestAjaxCall("#resultText");
    });

    $("#lnkApplyToAll").on('click', function () {
        console.log('Link Clicked');
        TestAjaxCall("#resultButton");
    });
};

TestAjaxCall = function (idToUpdate) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetString',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        data: { 'text': $("#txtAdjustment").autoNumericGet() },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log('Call to server was successful.');
            console.log('Set #foShiftTab');
            $(idToUpdate).html(result);
            console.log('initialize Shift Tab');
            console.log('done');
            InitializeFunction();
        },
        error: handleAjaxSystemError
    });
};

handleAjaxSystemError = function (result, e) {
    console.log('error: ' + result);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    InitializeFunction();
});
```

and here is the html:

```
<h2>Index</h2>
<input id="txtAdjustment" type="text" class="fo-adjustment" value="100%"/>
<a href="#" id="lnkApplyToAll" class="button">Apply To All</a>
<p id="resultText"></p>
<p id="resultButton"></p>
```

Comment: you shouldn't be calling `initializeFunction` more than once... it's binding click events, you don't want dupliclate events.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ya, i see it now, my bad!

Comment: Since the test code you posted works, it's going to be difficult for us to figure out why the production code doesn't.

Comment: The Production code would be overwhelming and hard to compress. The reason that initializeFunction is called like it is is because the actual ids of the html elements are dynamic. The production equivalent of that code takes an argument (id) and the element referencing code looks like $('txtAdjustment' + id). I was thinking the same thing, but removing that line of code doesn't fix the problem - only removing the entire ajax call appears to make both events fire.

Comment: I also posted to another site. More of the production code is there: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?294683-Only-one-of-two-events-occurs

Comment: I did make some progress on this issue. It has to do with BlockUI. When I remove those calls, it works as expected. If anyone knows about issues with AJAX calls and BlockUI, input is appreciated.